# The most searched keyword of the default search?

Tags: 7, search

Is there a way, or a module, to get the most searched keyword of the site's default search?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the "Top Search Phrases" report at "/admin/reports/search". This will give you a count of the search phrases used. It doesn't make it out by individual keyword, but at least gives you an idea of what people are searching for.